# tensorflow - assign name to optimizer for future restoration

Tags: tensorflow, save, restore

I create model in tensorflow and one of last lines in it is

```py
import tensorflow as tf
...
train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(some_loss_function)
```

I wonder if I can give this tensor/operation a name, so that that I can restore it by name after saving to disk?

Alternatively, if I cannot give it a name, how can I find it in output of
the following command:

```py
tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs for `tf.train.Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#minimize) yes, yes you can.

```py
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, name='my_training_step')
```

You can then restore the op later with:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver(...)
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, 'path/to/model')
train_op = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('my_training_step')
```

You can also store the training operation in a collection and restore it by [importing the meta graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph#Import_a_MetaGraph). Adding to a collection and saving looks like:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver(...)
tf.add_to_collection('train_step', train_step)
# ...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ...
    sess.save(sess, ...)
```

And restoring looks like:

```py
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('path/to/metagraph')
new_saver.restore(sess, 'path/to/model')
train_op = tf.get_collection('train_step')[0]  # restore the op
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you response. Just out of curiosity. Is it possible to find this operation in output of  `tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()`, in case I did not give it name during saving process?

Comment: I think it should be there, but the names can be a pain to parse through. I am not sure what it would look like in that case, sorry.

Comment: Oh, you may be able to find the name by inspecting the graph in tensorboard, provided you saved the graph at some point with `tf.train.Saver`.